# Deploy custom prebuilt model on Sagemaker

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I am newbee to ML world. I have a docker image which has the required custom model files.

Can some one please explain how to deploy this models as webservice?

I tried creating a endpoint and lambda function but no luck.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Also these models are trained so I don't need to train them

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tutorials on using your own models in SageMaker (you can skip the training sections since you already have a trained model).

- [Build your own docker image for training and deployment with scikit-learn](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/scikit_bring_your_own.ipynb)
- [Build your own docker image for training and deployment with R](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/r_bring_your_own/r_bring_your_own.ipynb)
- [Use a SageMaker pre-built KMeans algorithm image with custom model weights](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/kmeans_bring_your_own_model/kmeans_bring_your_own_model.ipynb)

A broad outline of what you will do in order to deploy as a webservice:

1. Package a docker image that follows a specification that allows SageMaker to interface with it, ex:- running an HTTP server that can respond to `/invocations` requests for inference. Details on this are available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-inference-code.html).
2. Create a SageMaker "Model" resource pointing to a registry hosting the docker image. API reference is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_CreateModel.html). You can also specify an optional S3 location for "model artifacts" - this is not required, but it can help if your development workflow separates your inference code from the model weights. This model can either be used for real-time prediction with SageMaker's Hosting services, or for performing batch inference with SageMaker's Batch Transform.
3. In order to deploy this for real-time inference, you can create an [endpoint configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_CreateEndpointConfig.html), followed by an [endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_CreateEndpoint.html). Details on this can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-hosting.html).
4. With the above steps, you should have a running HTTPS endpoint capable of returning predictions for queries, assuming your clients are able to sign requests using SigV4. If this is intended to be publicly visible, you can add API Gateway as the frontend, using it as a proxy to the SageMaker endpoint. Details can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-aws-proxy.html) (use "SageMaker Runtime" in Step 4).